# Cant exit twrp (reboot system doesn't work)

Tags: twrp

Using TWRP, I just installed new ROM (ResurrectionRemix-M-v5.7.4-20160922-libra) and OpenGApps (open_gapps-arm64-6.0-pico-20180830) on my *Xiaomi Readmi 4c.* Both of them were flashed successfully (or at least that's what the twrp said :D), there was no error or anything.

Then I went to "reboot system" and it returned back to the TWRP menu. I cannot boot into the newly flashed ROM.

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Too few details, sorry. Are you sure you flashed the right ROM, and everything went OK? Did you wipe anything before? What first comes to mind is a failed flash, so recovery is the only working system remaining – which would explain why you always end up there.

Comment: Yes the flash of the ROM and the open gapps were okay there was no error or anything.  I'm very new to this so I don't know if I'm using the proper terminology to explain the issue. I used the ResurrectionRemix-M-v5.7.4-20160922-libra ROM and open_gapps-arm64-6.0-pico-20180830. Both of them were flashed successfully (or at least that's what the twrp said :D).

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when the android phone doesn't have any ROM or the system itself so it redirects you to the recovery. One way for this is to wipe all out and re-flash everything OR wipe all out and re-flash a different ROM. And a question, Don't you have any backup of you're stock ROM before flashing a new one? It would be better to restore it.

Comment: This is not true to say this ONLY happens when there is no ROM or system to boot. I have a perfectly working system, which can boot, but only by going to bootloader, selecting "Start" from the menu and clicking the power button to select. It will boot android just fine and the system will function perfectly, as long as I do not shutdown. If I restart or boot from a shutdown, it will automatically boot into TWRP, at which time I have to go back into bootloader and select "Start" from the menu again in order to boot back into Android. Please don't make seemingly factual statements that are not f

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but someone may face this. For archive purposes -

By flashed successfully, TWRP only states that the process of flashing itself has completed without error. It does not test ROM compatibility with the device. While the information you have provided is too little to go by, it is likely that certain bootscripts are corrupted, or you are running tasks after that that corrupt (or erase) data. My recommendation would be to redownload the files and retry the process. If there is walkthrough content on the web, follow those. Check the device logs to ensure that there is no OS modification between installation and boot.